# Vue rendering of dynamic select options list

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I have a Vue where the AJAX fetched select options are not available the FIRST time the Vue is rendered.

I have done as suggested here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats.

The form is dynamically generated from a "schema" object.

```
<b-form-group v-for="(obj, key) in schema" 
  v-if="obj.type !== 'hidden'"
  :label="createInputLabel(obj, key)" :label-for="key" >
  ...
  <div v-else-if="obj.type == 'select'" role="group" 
    class="form-group">
    <select v-model="attributes[key]" :id="key" :name="key" 
      class="custom-select">
      <option v-for="option in optionsList[key]" 
        v-bind:value="option.value">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ...
</b-form-group>
```

optionsList is a keyed object containing lists of all the select elements on the form. optionsList is created by watching the "schema" object. The Rest API code is:

```
var idx = key;
Rest('GET', '/table/' + schema[key].table, requestParams, 
  this.$root.user.token)
.then(response => {      
   var localOptionsList = [];
   response.data.forEach(function(row) {
     var obj = { value: row[schema[idx].listColumns], 
       text: row[schema[idx].listColumns] };
     localOptionsList.push(obj);
   });
   Vue.set(me.optionsList, idx, localOptionsList);
})
.catch(error =>
  ...
```

As mentioned, the code works fine, apart from the FIRST time the Vue is rendered.

This is obviously because the data has not yet been returned from the Rest API, so my problem is how to get the Vue to react when the data arrives?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you updating schema object itself. Data is coming in and you'll notify anyone watching on optionList, but there is no code updating schema. You need to also update schema. This is ugly, but it should work: this.schema = this.schema.

Comment: 'schema' is updated when one of the props - 'module' - changes, i.e. a watcher on module sets schema, which has its own watcher. Module is set in the calling component, so schema is getting updated.

Comment: Ok, got it, but does the schema gets updated when optionLists gets updated, it seems like it does not, so you may need to updated it then.

Comment: it looks like your code is either cut off, or you actually put v-for together with v-if, which shouldn't be together in same element.